macOS ImageCaptureCore does not recognise scanners
I would like to develop a small macOS app using swift. I want to use ImageCaptureCore to access and control connected scanners ( via usb). I followed the official docs and wrote this ScannerManager. The code seems to be working without issues or warnings.
I added the Hardened Runtime capability and both com.apple.security.personal-information.photos-library and com.apple.security.device.usb to the .entitlements file.
As well added NSCameraUsageDescription to the Info.plist.
Problem: None of my scanners do gets detected (tested 2 different models).
class ScannerManager: NSObject, ICDeviceBrowserDelegate, ICDeviceDelegate {
  let deviceBrowser: ICDeviceBrowser
  private var currentDevice: ICDevice?
  private var scannerDeviceDelegate: ScannerDeviceDelegate?
  
  var isScanning = false
  var scanners: [ICDevice] = []
  
  // MARK: - Initialization
  
  override init() {
    print(" Initializing ScannerManager...")
    self.deviceBrowser = ICDeviceBrowser()
    super.init()
    
    self.deviceBrowser.delegate = self
    
    // Log the initial browsed device type mask
    self.deviceBrowser.browsedDeviceTypeMask = .scanner
    
    print(" Starting device browser...")
    self.deviceBrowser.start()
    
    // Enhanced device logging
    if let devices = deviceBrowser.devices {
      print("\n Connected devices overview:")
      print("Total devices found: \(devices.count)")
      if devices.isEmpty {
        print("⚠️ No devices currently connected")
      } else {
        devices.forEach { device in
          print("\n Device Details:")
          print("  - Name: \(device.name ?? "unnamed")")
          print("  - Type: \(String(describing: device.type))")
          print("  - Transport Type: \(String(describing: device.transportType))")
          print("  - Status: \(device.hasOpenSession ? "In Use" : "Available")")
          print("  - Persistent ID: \(String(describing: device.persistentIDString))")
          print("  - Location: \(device.locationDescription ?? "Unknown")")
          print("  - Capabilities: \(String(describing: device.capabilities))")
        }
      }
    } else {
      print("⚠️ Unable to access device list")
    }
  }
...

Of course, they are connected and do get recognized by the Image Capture App (and work as expected) and are listed in the systems app, too. When I connect my phone it does get detected by the
func deviceBrowser(_ browser: ICDeviceBrowser, didAdd...

delegate function. Thats why I believe my code is working but the app is lacking permissions to detect scanners somehow. Does anyone know something about this, or is there any hidden sample project?
I am using macOS 15.1.1 (24B91) on a M1 Pro.
Many thanks in advance!

Old archived sample code: ScannerBrowser
